# jQuery.holdReady

Tags: jquery

Какое именно событие ready, я буду приостанавливать либо возобновлять? Я понял, что этот метод для возобновления и остановки событий. Но как метод узнает, какого события, объясните на, что влияет этот метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это задержка загрузкы страницы `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Именно для этого метода придумано `holdReady`.